# Is there a macro which determines whether or not a command will produce printable output?

Tags: macros, output

In LaTeX, 'active' declarations (commands without argument) like `\Gamma` produce printable characters to the output stream while 'passive' ones like `\itshape` do not.  Is there a macro (or how to write one) which, given a LaTeX declaration as argument, will resolve whether the declaration is active or passive?

I need to be able to resolve this issue in order to correctly format the rendering of an input LaTeX argument with embedded declarations.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) A tip: you can use backticks `\`` to [mark your inline code](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/863/how-do-i-mark-inline-code) as I did in my edit.

Comment: The distinction between commands with and without arguments is not equivalent to that between those that write to the output document and those that do not - consider `\textit` vs `\itshape` and all the analogous font-changing commands for example.

Comment: Not really, your distinction of "active" and "passive" macros doesn't exist like that. Actually `\textit` is much more 'active' because it's changing the font(!) while `\Gamma` only prints a character. Also note that 'active' normally mean active characters with (La)TeX, like `~`. You could of course use a savebox (see `\sbox`) and measure the width of the resulting text which should be zero for "passive" macros. However, you need to provide the right number of dummy arguments....

Comment: My use of the descriptions 'active' and 'passive' were coined ad hoc to distinguish between those declarations that write to the output stream and those that do not.  I am not concerned with what is going on 'behind the scene' so to speak.  I think you misunderstand my question.  I need to know a priori if a LaTex command will or will not produce output.  For example I need to be able to determine for the Latex inputfor any conmmand \declaration

Comment: My previous post was away before finished so ...

Comment: I'll get the hang of this in due course.  For example I need to be able to determine for the LaTex input 'This is a <\declaration> test' whether <\declaration> will output characters or not for whatever specific LaTex \declaration is used.  I hope that that is clearer.

Comment: @darrelld: Note that you can edit your comments for 5min after posting them. You can't use ENTER in them (but SHIFT+ENTER) because this automatically sends them. Also you can use back-ticks `\`` to format inline code.

Comment: @darrelld: I understood you correctly and my answer stands: You can't! The only way is to measure the result. If you explain your actual problem than we might be able to help you better.

Comment: @Martin Scharrer  Here is the scenario.  I have written a macro to render arbitrary LaTex text input into so-called Title Case.  The input can contain Latex declarations (and maths code).   After a declaration like `\itshape` one doesn't want a space but after one like `\&` one does.  The problem is to determine prior to output whether the declaration will produce output in order to apply correct formatting. Of course user intervention would solve this problem but I want to avoid that if I can.

Comment: @darrelld: That won't work like that. A user defined macro could contain several words which you macro would then miss. The closest thing to your macro would be either `\MakeUppercase` or the `soul` package which also tries to handle formatting macros in a special way.

Comment: @darrelld: If I understand correctly, you are looking for a `\TitleCase` macro such that `\TitleCase{heLlo \itshape worlD \& friends!}` typesets "Hello _World_ & Friends!"? But why would you need to add a space particularly after the `&`? Shouldn't it be put by the user?

Comment: @Bruno Le Floch Agreed I just used `\&` as an examle of an active declaration.  The real point here is you don't want to put a space after `\itshape`; for then you have a double space after Hello. I've actually written a macro but have difficulty handling declarations without user intervention.

Comment: @Martin: please post your savebox comment as an answer (see comment of darrelld on my "answer").

Answer (score 1):

This is not an answer to the question as currently stated. Given some comments of darrelld, I believe that the goal is to define a macro, `\TitleCase`, which puts its argument in, well, title case. This can be done with varying degrees of robustness, but one way is to read tokens one at a time and convert letters using `\uppercase` and `\lowercase`.

Here, `\TitleCase@case` is at all times either `\uppercase` or `\lowercase`: it is set to `\uppercase` at the very start of the `\TitleCase` command, and after each space. It is set to `\lowercase` by any letter.

The result is stored one piece at a time into `\TitleCase@tl`, and used at the end.

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\TitleCase@tl}{}
\newcommand*{\TitleCase@case}{}
\newcommand*{\TitleCase@marker}{\TitleCase@marker}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\TitleCase}[1]
  {%
    \let\TitleCase@tl\empty
    \let\TitleCase@case\uppercase
    \TitleCase@#1\TitleCase@marker
    \TitleCase@tl
  }
\newcommand*{\TitleCase@}{\futurelet\@let@token\TitleCase@@}
\newcommand*{\TitleCase@@}
  {%
    \ifcase 0%
        \ifcat\noexpand\@let@token\bgroup 1\fi
        \ifx\@let@token\@sptoken 2\fi
        \ifx\@let@token\TitleCase@marker 3\fi
      \relax
        \expandafter\TitleCase@normal
    \or \expandafter\TitleCase@group
    \or \expandafter\TitleCase@space
    \or \expandafter\@gobble
    \fi
  }
\newcommand{\TitleCase@normal}[1]
  {%
    \TitleCase@case
      {%
        \expandafter\def\expandafter\TitleCase@tl\expandafter
          {\TitleCase@tl #1}%
      }%
    \ifcat A\noexpand\@let@token
      \let\TitleCase@case\lowercase
    \fi
    \TitleCase@
  }%
\newcommand{\TitleCase@group}[1]
  {%
    \begingroup
      \let\TitleCase@tl\empty
      \TitleCase@ #1\TitleCase@marker
      \expandafter
    \endgroup
    \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\def
    \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\TitleCase@tl
    \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{%
      \expandafter\TitleCase@tl\expandafter{\TitleCase@tl}}%
    \TitleCase@
  }
\newcommand{\TitleCase@space}
  {\afterassignment\TitleCase@space@\let\@let@token= }
\newcommand{\TitleCase@space@}
  {%
    \let\TitleCase@case\uppercase
    \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\def
    \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\TitleCase@tl
    \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{\expandafter\TitleCase@tl\space}%
    \TitleCase@
  }
\makeatother
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
  \section{\TitleCase{helLo, \itshape wo\textup{Rl}D!}}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @ Bruno Le Floch:  Thank you for putting time and thought into this macro.  It is along the same lines as I have already done but, not being a TEXnician, using higher level LaTex commands from the `xstring` package. Your macro renders what I would call Initial Capital Case which is somewhat different from what I understand by the more subtle Title Case. Never mind, I think that I can see my way forward using save boxes as Martin Scharrer suggests.  Strangely I have tried that approach before but without success till now.